# SMS Concatenation and MobileConnect API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, mobileconnect

I'm working with MobileConnect to create notification text messages that will be triggered through the API. Further, there can be multiple notifications per contact/mobile number for an individual send.

I would like to be to use the messageContact endpoint (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm) in order to batch text messages and utilize a single API call to send to up to 250 per call and still use dynamic content and send a really personalized text message.

However, the end point doesn't accept duplicate subscribers in the same call. I want an individual have the ability to receive multiple text messages (though this is an edge case).

```
{
"Subscribers": [
    {
    "MobileNumber": "15555555555",
    "SubscriberKey": "003f200002eatnZAAQ",
    "Attributes":{
        "FirstName":"Test1"
        }
    },
    {
    "MobileNumber": "15555555555",
    "SubscriberKey": "003f200002eatnZAAQ",
    "Attributes":{
        "FirstName":"Test1"
        }
    }
],
"Subscribe": "true",
"Resubscribe": "true",
"keyword": "JOIN",
"Override": "false"
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "The subscriber object [15555555555,003f200002eatnZAAQ] has a duplicate subscriber key specified."
    ]
}
```

My potential workaround is to use create a single text message using the Concatenate Message feature. [image: SMS Concatenation]

Other than costing more than one message, are there any unintended consequences I should be aware of? This is for a U.S. based short code. While the short code supports it, do the majority of carriers/phones support concatenation? My concern is going down this route and learning after the fact that a good portion of the recipients don't receive the messages correctly.

One Twilio article (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181508-Does-Twilio-support-concatenated-SMS-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters-) mentions not being supported by Sprint and US Cellular. I personally have Sprint and am able to receive concatenated messages from Marketing Cloud so perhaps the article is outdated.

Thank you, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The endpoint does accept multiple phones in the same payload. Can you post the payload you are trying to send?

Comment: Hi Rufenstein, I can get it to accept the multiple phone numbers. It cannot accept duplicate subscriber key data. I'll edit my post for clarity and also add the payload/error

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation isn't supported by most US carriers so you will find that it won't provide the same experience to each subscriber.

Also, the behavior you are finding that a subscriberkey can't be replicated in the same call is accurate and intentional and not a bug. You will have to manage that by making sure they aren't in the same payload.